# Proof that checking if a graph has a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Hi am reading [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~saia/classes/362-s08/lec/lec24-2x2.pdf](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Esaia/classes/362-s08/lec/lec24-2x2.pdf) proving that the problem of checking if a graph has a hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete. It uses the fact that the problem of checking if a graph has a vertex cover of a given size is NP-complete, and it reduces the problem of vertex cover to the problem of Hamiltonian cycle (thus contradicting it not being NP-hard).

There are a few things I don't understand:

- I see there is a construction of the gadgets, but I don't understand what the big picture is: how do we obtain G' from G? How do we put the gadgets together?
- What is the motivation for this? I don't think I would have come up with anything like it on my own, and I'm trying to develop the skill of designing gadgets. I was trying to solve this on my own before I looked it up, but I didn't really get anywhere?

Comment: The way gadgets are put together is described in slide "vertex chains" and an example is given in slide "example". These reductions using gadgets can often be non-trivial, so there is no general methodology for it. Generally, when attempting such a proof, we ask how we could chain hypothetical gadgets together (supposing we can find gadgets satisfying some needed conditions), and then we search for gadgets (intuition, brute force...). Note that this reduction is not an easy one, many gadget-based reductions are much more intuitive. Here, a chain of thoughts that could lead to this reduction:

Comment: We want to model a long chain visiting exactly $k$ neighborhoods of vertices, so we set up $k$ cover vertices that will help to count the neighborhoods (because we cannot go through a vertex twice). Then for each cover vertices, we allow it to visit a chosen neighborhood by a path. Now that the plan is established, we need to look at what the gadget will look like. An edge can be covered by one of the two or by its two extremities, so we need to set up a gadget that accounts for these three cases. The construction of the gadget can be found by intuition or brute force.